# При отмене уведомлений в трее, лампочка телефона продолжает мигать

Tags: java, android

Я сделал уведомления в трее через NotificationManager. Помимо звукового сигнала и вибрации, есть ещё индикация светодиода. Т.е. лампочка телефона начинает мигать. 
Когда пользователь заходит в определённую активити, где он может прочитать все эти уведомления в развёрнутом виде, я очищаю все уведомления в трее. Делаю это так: notificationManager.cancel(PUSH_ID);

Уведомления пропадают, но лампочка всё-равно продолжает мигать. И перестаёт мигать только лишь после того как я заблокирую, а потом разблокирую экран.

Как побороть эту проблему? Мне надо чтобы после очистки уведомлений также перестал мигать и индикатор.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл проблему. Я делаю очистку в отдельном классе. Для этого я передаю в методе в качестве аргумента Context. Но в активити я передавал this, а надо было getApplicationContext().

Теперь после замены всё стало нормально.